# On new custom field, how to setup a data type of Formula and output type of Checkbox?

Tags: formula-field, custom-field, data-types

Checkbox will come back as true if these employee conditions are met: are in the US, are full time, are active and have a start date after 1/1/2018.

No syntax errors, but the checkbox on Team Member record is blank: (fHCM2__Has_Left__c = 'FALSE') && (fHCM2__Country__c = 'USA') && (fHCM2__Current_Employment__r.fHCM2__FTE__c >= 1) && (fHCM2__Current_Employment__r.fHCM2__Start_Date__c >= DATE(1,2,2018))

[image]

Comment: That's not real personal data, is it?

Comment: The formula checkbox field isn't "blank", it's just showing a `false` result. I would suggest taking out different conditions in the formula until you get a positive checkmark in the box.  Then add conditions back in to identify which one is making this checkbox `false`

Comment: @DavidReed - No

Comment: @BrianMiller - I'll give it a whirl; thanks!